# How to activate my windows server license on an existing Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an existing 2019 windows server license. How do I activate it on a running Azure windows 2022 VM?

How do I actually make use of the product key? Where should I enter it inorder to activate the windows license on the VM?

Comment: I would recommend directing this question at the Microsoft tech support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I actually make use of the product key? Where should I enter it inorder to activate the windows license on the VM?

If you have `Windows Server 2019` license, you can use the same key in an `Azure VM` by selecting the `Hybrid Benefit` option while creating the `Azure VM`, this will save up to 49% with a license if you already have a Windows license.

[image]

`Azure VM` by default comes with license activation. To save costs, you can change the product key with your existing license key as shown below.

[image]

Refer: [Explore Azure Hybrid Benefit for Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hybrid-use-benefit-licensing?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Compute)